# Port already Using Error in Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have an android application which is running on Huawei S7,Android 2.2. It is getting inputs from an arduino board.Arduino Board is connected to the tablet by USB cable.Application is using USB Protocol to connect to arduino.

The application is written for Android 4.1.And it is using a backward compatibility pack to make it runnable on 2.2. We had to use a 2.2 device.But now we have a device with Android 4.3. And when we try to run the same app in 4.3 device it gives an error saying 4567 port already in use. 4567 port is the port used by arduino application to connect with the Android Device(Tablet Application).

How can i find the application which is using the 4567 port?

Is there any way i can free up that port?

My 4.3 device is not rooted. Will rooting do any good in this problem?

Comment: You could check whether the `netstat` binary is available on your device. It's a command line tool, so you'd either need a terminal app or an ADB connection to use it. `netstat --tcp --listening -p` then should list up all listening ports together with the associated "program" (didn't try this on Android, so I'm not sure whether all options are supported. If you can confirm this, I'll write up an answer).

Comment: I used terminal emulator app and ran the above command. 
This is the output i got.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oZFpqRGJkcUV0cDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do i need the root access to run this command?

Comment: Just a second: Your linked screenshot does *not* use above command. You ran `lsof` (LiSt Open Files). I wrote `netstat --tcp --listening -p`. Complete different commands, for different purposes (though partly overlapping). Please ty again :) And no, it should not require root to run `netstat` (though the `-p` parameter *might* ask for it, depending on implementation).

Comment: Sorry i linked the wrong screen shot. I was trying that command suggested by another stackexchange site user.This is the one i got when running netstat --tcp --listening -p

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7od1BzN1BaR1ZGNWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. If I interprete it correctly, there's either nothing listening on any TCP port altogether – or at least nothing you have access to. As indicated by my last comment, `-p` might require root permissions (at least according to its man pages). Try again without that parameter to see whether the list is really empty. If not, you've found out if rooting will *do any good in this problem* ;)

Comment: These are the outputs i get when i try that without the -p
#1 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oalJtaUVvVkdQd1E/edit?usp=sharing
#2 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oMy04TnB3QXlIeG8/edit?usp=sharing

#3 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7objRONnR3MEUwM1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In that case, my assumption was correct and `-p` requires root. `-p` would show you the app along the result list's entries, so you could figure out which app stands behind it. Looks like without root that's not possible – at least not in this way. But I've just found an app that might do the trick: [NetStat Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/netstat-plus/com.rinacode.android.netstatplus). You might wish to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional tools, this should be possible via `adb shell` or a terminal app, using the `netstat` command: `netstat --tcp --listening -p` should list up all listening ports along with the app behind it. But it might very well be (as in your case, obviously) that the `-p` parameter requires root; and without it, the output won't show the app holding the port open.

However, [NetStat Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/netstat-plus/com.rinacode.android.netstatplus) might offer what you need:

[image: NetStat Plus] [image: Connection List]
<sup>*NetStat Plus* and *Connection List* (source: Google Play; click for larger image)</sup>

I did not try this app myself, but the screenshots suggest it does exactly what you need: Listing apps with the used ports and status along. No word that it requires root. It further seems to work at least from Gingerbread (2.3.6 is explicitly mentioned) onwards to at least Jelly Bean 4.3 (also explicitly mentioned). An alternative would be [Connection List](http://www.appbrain.com/app/connection-list-free/net.bananenfisch.connectionlistlite) (second screenshot).

Comment: I tried both the apps but any record they generate doesn't show any app using the port 4657. :( 
Shall i give the screen shots of those too?

Comment: I don't think that will help. At least the screenshot of *Connection list* shows it deals with ports in `LISTENING` mode as well. So if no such is shown with any of the apps (and `netstat --tcp --listening | grep ":4657"` doesn't yield a result either, then there isn't anything listening there. Maybe some *outgoing* session was just using the very same port? Have you checked that? If that's the case, it might already be freed again. Try to start your app again. If it fails with the same error, use one of those apps to check for all entries with that port (not only `LISTENING`).

Comment: I ran the netstat --tcp --listening | grep ":4657" command and got this result.
It has 4567 in it but the complete port number is 45675.I guess it's not the same. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oMU5NREhldEQwZjA/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7od3RuMjlJLU1CNk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is as much the same as 4,657 USD and 46,575 USD are the same :) Please, try again with your app. If it shows the same error, check with the apps again as described (and optionally `netstat --tcp | grep ":4657"` for the general information whether the port is in use, and if so, in which state). Assuming either `ESTABLISHED` or `CLOSE_WAIT`, another app could be using it for outgoing connections.